# What web technologies should I use to add a random string to an icalendar url?

Tags: email, url, random, ms-project

I am using microsoft project to send out many emails at once that all have url's in them. These urls contain private information and the issue is that by changing one or two numbers in the id of the url, people can see information that they arent supposed to be seeing. So, to make it more secure I want to add ajkw42HH or some other random string to the url so that people cant just change one or two numbers and get another valid url? Then obviously whoever is opening it in their browser needs to be able to take this random string off so that they can see and visit the original url. Can anyone give me a good starting place perhaps or some good keywords. Im lost right now

Comment: `These urls contain private information` -- Fail.  Munging the URL isn't going to solve your privacy problem.  If these pages really contain private information, they need to be secured behind a user login.

Comment: ok well its not that private. It would just be better if you couldnt see other peoples urls